# HP Spectre x360 13" 2016 brighness not working

Tags: drivers, brightness, hp

I have tried multiple variants of Linux on my said hardware, but each one of them has been unable to change brightness.  Both the dedicated hardware buttons and UI sliders do affect the brightness and the the display remains at full brightness, hurt s my eyes, and wastes battery.  Am I missing a drivers or is there another solution.  I should add that I currently run Antergos GNOME and the spectre has no dedicated graphics card i.e. Intel graphics.

Comment: Have you [checked this page out?](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/display-brightness.html.en)

Answer (score 0):

Can you find a `brightness` file in `/sys/class/backlight`? I have Intel graphics and on my system, and writing a number into `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` changes the brightness.

Comment: The only problem is that I can't overide it, even as root user.